# How to use ALB as a target group for NLB to enable SSH cloning in bitbucket?

Tags: ssh, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer, nlb

We are trying to configure Load balancer to route the traffic between bitbucket nodes(data center model), we did that successfully using ALB.

Our Bitbucket application is up and running.

But we couldn't enable SSH cloning with ALB, since it will not support we had to go with either CLB or NLB.

We decided to go with configuring SSH traffic via NLB and configuring ALB as a target group for NLB.

Had gone through few documents and threads regarding this, but we couldn't be able to properly configure ALB as a Target group for NLB.

Posting here to understand is it the right way to utilize the load balancers this way or what is the proper way to enable SSH clone with load balancers.

Am sure someone might be installed Bitbucket datacenter model this way, happy to learn the proper way.

Comment: Pretty confident this won't work - ALBs are for HTTP traffic on Layer 7, and they do not understand other protocols like SSH.

Comment: Thanks for your input, yes we are aware that with ALB we cannot enable SSH traffic. That's why i have explained about integration NLB with ALB as a target group.

Comment: I saw that, but it doesn't change the fact that ALBs are *only* for HTTP. The best you could do here is use the NLB to separate HTTP or HTTPS traffic (by destination port) and then send only that traffic to the ALB; the SSH traffic will still not be able to use the ALB.